# Docker container in different HW architecture

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, arm

Is it possible to have same container on my pc and on raspberry(or any other architecture)?

The reason for this is that I want to develop some web app on pc and then just put it to raspberry or any other device running docker.What will be the compatibility issues? What limits the container from being used on another arch?

Can I somehow convert between armv7/armhf-ubuntu and plain official ubuntu based image?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same Dockerfile, but you will need to build an image for each architecture.

When I say architecture, keep in mind that a Raspberry Pi, an Odroid from Hardkernel.com and a Beaglebone, are all "ARM", but are different, and will need specific images.

And of course, x86 and ARM are different.

Comment: So I am free to choose any architecture for any dockerfile. There are no limitation that apply for those dockerfiles? I can run oracle image anywhere?

Comment: If your Oracle image runs on Raspberry yes. I may be mistaken, but I do not see ARM on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: So how can I know the image can be build for specific arch? Try? I hope I can find out during build.

Comment: Can you explain how you build the image?

Comment: You wrote that I need to build the image. I don't know how it is done. I'm asking if it is posible to run every dockerfile everywhere,seems it is not. How will i find out? I need to check the base image and all used binaries in my dockerfile?

Comment: See if you find all what you need to build your image in https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129112/discussion-between-user2915097-and-zveratko).

Comment: [Here](http://blog.ubergarm.com/run-arm-docker-images-on-x86_64-hosts/) is great way how to do it. It is not optimal, but might work. Use arm image on x_86 arch. Something like lowest common denominator image. Not sure what will be the performance hit.

Comment: You have to see if the performance penalty is acceptable (I guess yes). I have gone the other way, running x86-64 executables on ARM, using qemu-i386 (you need to recompile it), copy various files (from x86 /lib/i386-linux-gnu and other directories to ARM), and then launch `qemu-i386 /opt/abc/my_soft`